# Convert Expression<Func<T, bool?>> to Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, expression

Simple question really.

I have MVC view that displays a Nullable Bool, e,g,

```
Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.NullableBoolHere, Model.NullableBoolHere,
```

and I want to create a new html helper, that will accept this type, and then convert

```
Null || False => False
True => True
```

so I have the following

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool?>> expression, object htmlAttributes, bool disabled)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> values = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);

        if (disabled)
            values.Add("disabled", "true");

        Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> boolExpression = CONVERT_TO_BOOL_HERE(expression);


        return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression, values);
    }
```

Any help appreciated, I understand I will have to use recursion to copy the expression, but just not sure how to go about navigating the expression itself, find the bool?, convert to bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the end, the only way I could find to do it was to resolve the bool? into a bool myself, then return a 'normal' checkbox by passing in the correct name etc.

This does work a treat though, so all good. If you do know a better way of getting the correct ParameterName, it would be great to hear.

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool?>> expression, object htmlAttributes, bool disabled)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> values = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);

        if (disabled)
            values.Add("disabled", "true");

        //Compile the expression to get the value from it.
        var compiled = expression.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
        bool checkValue = compiled.HasValue ? compiled.Value : false; //evaluate the compiled expression

        //Get the name of the id we should use
        //var parameterName = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name; // only gives the last part
        string parameterName = expression.Body.ToString().Replace("model.", "");//.Replace(".", HtmlHelper.IdAttributeDotReplacement);

        //Return our 'hand made' checkbox
        return htmlHelper.CheckBox(parameterName, checkValue, values);
    }
```

Comment: Also possible syntax: var b= e.Compile()(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model); No need to use Invoke

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
var body = Expression.Coalesce(expression.Body, Expression.Constant(false));
var boolExpression = (Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>)
    Expression.Lambda(body, expression.Parameters.First());
```

The advantage to the other answers is that it doesn't compile the first expression, it just wraps it. The resulting expression is similar to one created by this code:

```
m => m.NullableBoolHere ?? false
```

[Check it live](http://ideone.com/R5rrhi).

Comment: I like what you've done here, makes sense. Seems following this I then hit an MVC issue, I get the error "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions." But I'll play around with this and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: @adudley: In that case the MVC engine restricts the expressions it allows, because it will actually not execute them but parse them and generate some code based on the parsed expression tree. To keep the parsing logic relatively simple, it places heavy restrictions on what actually is allowed in that expressions. You are better off just creating a property in your model that wraps `NullableBoolHere`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it won't be enough to just convert the expression to another type, MVC uses expressions for a reason so I suspect it needs to examine the given expression and apply some magic on it.

You can create a new expression that does the conversion, like this:

```
 Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> boolExpression = 
        T => expression.Compile()(T).GetValueOrDefault(false);
```

But as I said, I suspect it will not be enough, MVC probably wants to examine model members etc inside the expression.

Comment: Yeah, I get an error, as expected. MVC need to 'read' the un compiled expression to do 'magic' with ! "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> boolExpression = model =>
        {
             bool? result = expression.Compile()(model);

             return result.HasValue ? result.Value : false;
        };
```

That way you wrap the original expression and you can convert the result from bool? to bool.

Does it solve your problem?