# convert Expression<Func<TModel, string>> to Expression<Func<TModel, TimeSpan?>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, lambda, html-helper

I have a static method declared and implemented as such : method 1

```
public static MvcHtmlString TimePickerFor<TModel>
  (this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
   Expression<Func<TModel, TimeSpan?>> expression)
```

I need to implement an overload of the above to call method 1 from 
method 2

method 2 declaration:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TimePickerFor<TModel>
  (this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
   Expression<Func<TModel, string>> expression)
```

not sure how to implement this method 2 implementation:

```
Expression<Func<TModel, TimeSpan?>> expression2 = DoSomethingTo(expression)
TimePickerFor(Model, expression2)
```

Update : from answer [Convert Expression<Func<T, bool?>> to Expression<Func<T, bool>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356611/convert-expressionfunct-bool-to-expressionfunct-bool?rq=1) it seems this is a futile exercise, MVC needs todo magic with the expression. So even if this conversion was possible it will not work.

Comment: Is this limited to member expressions like `m => m.StartDate` or there could be anything in expression body?

Comment: @Dennis : I haven't encountered anything else besides member expressions in MVC, for now I am happy to just go with member expressions only, can you also give example of expression that has something in expression body and some places that they are used please? I like to know what topics I need to research further.

Comment: E.g., `m => CallSomeMethod(m.StartDate)` expression will have different body (method call -> member access as argument). I'm not sure, that I could give you any usage sample in context of the question. It was just a request about limitations of possible answer.

Comment: @Dennis : It was also informative, I have updated my question, at the bottom. It basically is not useful, since MVC needs to do it's magic, so conversion wont be useful in this case , or so it seems.